# issue accesing one service from another kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Trying to connect to one service from another in the same namespace. Using ClusterIP for creating the service. once the service is created use that Ip to access the service. Requests are successful sometimes and sometimes it is failing, I see both the pods are up and running. Below is the service configuration

```
apiVersion: v1 kind: Service metadata: name: serviceA spec: selector: app: ServiceA ports: - name: http port: 80 targetPort: 8080 type: ClusterIP

apiVersion: v1 kind: Service metadata: name: serviceB spec: selector: app: ServiceB ports: - name: http port: 80 targetPort: 8123 type: ClusterIP
```

Comment: share the yaml of both config.

Answer (score 0):

Please use service name in invoking it as below

```
http://serviceA:80
```

K8s offers [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)
Kubernetes creates DNS records for Services and Pods. You can contact Services with consistent DNS names instead of IP addresses.